# does all the functions inside a constexpr function in constexpr context must be constexpr function?

Tags: c++

In ubuntu gcc 8.0:

```
void bar(){}

constexpr int foo(int a)
{
    if (a <=0 )
        bar();

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a1[foo(-1)]; //will give a compile error, which is expected, 
                     //since non-constexpr function is not allowd in constexpr context
}
```

But in the following test:

```
int main()
{
    int a2[foo(1)];  //no compile error
}
```

Here, bar is non-constexpr function. 
I am wondering why non-constexpr function is allowed in constexpr context although in this test it doesn't get called.

Comment: I didn't get error though. I'm using g++ 7.3.0 Ubuntu

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis I am using g++ 8.0 with -std=c++17

Comment: g++-8 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04) 8.2.0, `-std=c++17`, still no error

Comment: Can't repro. On my g++ (same setup, more or less), it runs, same as ZisIsNotZis.

Comment: Is that code correct? Is the top example meant to be `bar` and the bottom example `foo` or am I missing something

Comment: Here is the full command : g++  -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -O2 -o m main.cpp -pedantic-errors -std=c++17

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis the error only occurs with -pedantic-errors

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis You can also try it here : https://godbolt.org/z/z1QQ3t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **does all the functions inside a constexpr function in constexpr context must be constexpr function?**

It depends.

The fact that calls to non-constexpr functions are allowed in `constexpr` functions doesn't mean that  all possible calls to the `constexpr` function must result in a *constant expression*, but for context in which a *constant expression* is needed (like in array bounds), the call to the `constexpr` function must evaluate to a *constant expression*

The related parts of the standard for this case are:

`[dcl.constexpr]/5`

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, **if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (8.20)**, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object (6.6.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

`[expr.const]/2`

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (4.6), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - (2.2) an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor [...]

This means that a `constexpr` function can have on its body calls to non-constexpr functions as long as there exist some arguments for which it evaluate to a *constant expression* or subexpression thereof, that's the reason why you can use `foo(1)` as value for the array bound, because it evaluation doesn't involve the call to `bar()` which is not the case for `foo(-1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Use c++14 standard to compile your code:

```
$ 
$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++14
$ ./a.out
1
$ cat main.cpp
//
//  main.cpp
//
//
//  Created by myhaspl on 2018/10/24.
//  myhaspl@myhaspl.com.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bar(){}

constexpr int foo(int a)
{
    if (a <=0 )
        bar();

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a1[2]={0,1};

    cout<<a1[foo(-1)]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) verbatim, and without attribution?