# call basic_string function in constexpr funnction

Tags: c++, c++11

i search didn't find much about constexpr function. C++ primer says the return type and the type of each parameter in a must be a literal type. And now return type i use bool and parameters type i use reference.but in the return i use two basic_string function to calculation results.clion is tell me can't use basic_string function in constexpr function

```
constexpr bool a (const string &z , const string &zz)
{
    return (z.size() > zz.size());
}
```

Thank you very much for answering my question！

Comment: The problem is that, IIRC, `std::string` simply has no `constexpr` constructors until at least C++20 (inclusive). You could probably use a `std::string_view` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that all the types you used are *literal types*, but there is another requirement for a `constexpr` function.

A `constexpr` function must be callable for at least one set of arguments so that the call is a constant expression.

The problem is that `z.size()` can never be called in a constant expression, because `string`'s `size` function is not declared `constexpr`.

If a function declared `constexpr` can never be used as a constant expression, then the program has *undefined behavior* and the compiler may or may not warn or print an error about it.

If you change the function in a way that can be used as a constant expression for at least one set of call arguments, then there will be no error on the definition anymore:

```
constexpr bool a (bool b, const string &z , const string &zz)
{
    return b ? false : (z.size() > zz.size());
}
```

You can still not call this as part of a constant expression with `b` as `false` though.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you can make this function work (assuming it is called with arguments that are usable in a constant expression) by using `string_view` instead of `const string&` since C++17. (Requires `#include<string_view>`). This works because `std::string_view` is a literal type (in particular it has `constexpr` constructors) and its `size` function *is* `constexpr` as well.

Comment: sorry , i have two questions . first , i found a qunstion is use a not declared constexpr function in a constexpr function .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960040/does-all-the-functions-inside-a-constexpr-function-in-constexpr-context-must-be

Comment: @Nater I think the answer in the linked question basically says the same thing as I did. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: my previous question is why .size() function can never be called in a constant expression but a general function can be call

Comment: @Nater A call to a non-`constexpr` function can appear in a `constexpr` function's definition, but it can not be actually be called in a constant expression. That means that if the non-`constexpr` function *would* be called through the `constexpr` function, then the whole expression in which the call appears is not a constant expression. This is the same for `.size()` and for `bar()` in the question that you linked.

Comment: The problem is then that, although a call to a non-`constexpr` function can appear in a `constexpr` function, a function cannot be `constexpr` if it will *always* evaluate the non-`constexpr` call, because a `constexpr` function must be usable as constant expression for at least one set of possible arguments. This last requirement basically protects you from writing `constexpr` functions that cannot actually be used at compile-time. It is important to realize that `constexpr` means "*can sometimes be evaluated at compile-time*", not "*can always be evaluated at compile-time*".

Answer (score 0):

I think the top answerin [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) thread can also be very helpful in answering your question.